# Можно ли сказать: "Найти огромный выбор"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В написании текста по качеству алкогольной продукции столкнулся с такой трудность. Сперва написал так: "Сейчас в любом продуктовом магазине можно найти огромный выбор алкогольной продукции". Но потом показалось, что нельзя сказать "найти огромный выбор". Выкинул словосочетание "можно найти", получилось: "Сейчас в любом продуктовом магазине огромный выбор алкогольной продукции". Такой вариант понравился больше. Но вообще, допустим ли оборот, употребленным в первом случае: "найти огромный выбор"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше сказать: "Сейчас в любом продуктовом магазине существует широкий выбор алкогольной продукции".Или: "Сейчас в любом продуктовом магазине можно найти огромный ассортимент алкогольной продукции". Или: " Сейчас в любом продуктовом магазине алгкогольная продукция представлена в огромном ассортименте".

А вот "найти огромный выбор" - это не очень удачная фраза, так как выбор - это многозначное слово со следующими значениями: 1. Процесс выбора (название действия). 2. О том, кто выбран или что выбрано. Мой выбор. 3. То, из чего можно выбрать,ассортимент. Широкий в. товаров.

Отсюда следует семантическая неясность сочетания "найти выбор" (можно понять как просто "выбрать", а не "найти ассортимент") и вследствие этого непопулярность такого сочетания.

Comment: Но,  в  принципе,  сказать  так  можно.